# How to automatically redirect users from http:// to https://?

Tags: apache, http, svn, https, visualsvn-server

When I want to switch my SVN users and the server to use encrypted HTTPS protocol instead of plain HTTP, the users will also need to relocate their working copies to new https:// URLs or checkout new working copies using the new URLs. URL adjustments in scripts may also be required.

I want to make the transition from HTTP to HTTPS painless and transparent for the end users. Is it possible to implement automatic HTTP to HTTPS redirection with SVN and Apache? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from VisualSVN Server 3.6, you can enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection via server settings. There is an option on the **Network** tab: **Automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS (listen on port 80)**. Learn more at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00144/.

[image: VisualSVN Server Manager Network Tab HTTP to HTTPS]